# Error Populating Dropdownlist in Gridview Footer Template in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to implement a cascading dropdownlist in a gridview footer template. My code is given below. I am getting an error message "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**"

My ASPX Page

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="950px"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Segoe UI Symbol"
                Font-Size="11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White"
                HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" 
                AllowPaging="true" ShowFooter="true" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2"
                OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" DataKeyNames="ServiceID"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowCreated ="GridView1_RowCreated" 
                PageSize="20" CellPadding="4">

                <Columns>

                     <%--ServiceID--%>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="ServiceID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblServiceID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServiceId")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>



                    <%--Grand Parent Service --%>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Grand Parent">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblGrandParentService" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GrandService")%>'></asp:Label>

                            </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGrandParentService" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="150" onselectedindexchanged="ddlGrandParentService_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>

                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGrandParentService" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="150" onselectedindexchanged="ddlGrandParentService_SelectedIndexChanged">  
                             </asp:DropDownList>  
                         </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <%-- Parent Service --%>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Parent Service">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblParentService" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ParentServiceName")%>'></asp:Label>

                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParentService" runat="server" Width="150" >
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>

                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParentService" runat="server" Width="150">
                            </asp:DropDownList>                            
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>                  
            </asp:GridView>



protected void ddlGrandParentService_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList ddlGrandParent = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddlGrandParent.NamingContainer;
        if (row != null)
        {
            if ((row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                DropDownList ddlParent = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlParentService");
                ddlParent.DataSource = GetParentServiceByGrandParent(Convert.ToInt32(ddlGrandParent.SelectedValue));
                ddlParent.DataValueField = "ParentServiceID";
                ddlParent.DataTextField = "ParentServiceName";
                ddlParent.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }




public void GridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        DropDownList ddlGrandParent = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlGrandParentService");

        ddlGrandParent.DataSource = GetGrandParentService();
        ddlGrandParent.DataValueField = "GrandParentServiceID";
        ddlGrandParent.DataTextField = "GrandService";
        ddlGrandParent.DataBind();

        //ddlGrandParent.SelectedValue = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        DropDownList ddlParent = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlParentService");

        //**Getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

        ddlParent.DataSource = GetParentServiceByGrandParent  (Convert.ToInt32((GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlGrandParentService") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value));

        ddlParent.DataValueField = "ParentServiceId";
        ddlParent.DataTextField = "ParentServiceName";
        ddlParent.DataBind();
    }
}

private List<GrandParentService> GetGrandParentService()
{

    List<GrandParentService> all = new List<GrandParentService>();
    using (HospitalEntities dc = new HospitalEntities())
    {
        all = dc.GrandParentService.ToList();
    }

    return all;
}

private List<ParentService> GetParentServiceByGrandParent(int grandParentID)
{

    List<ParentService> all = new List<ParentService>();
    using (HospitalEntities dc = new HospitalEntities())
    {
        all = dc.ParentService.Where(a => a.GrandParentServiceID.Equals(grandParentID)).ToList();
    }

    return all;
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a dropdown with id "ddlGrandParentService" AND "ddlGrandParentService" in your footer template? The error says that it could not find the control with id "ddlParentService".

Comment: Yes i have the two dropdownlist.

Comment: <FooterTemplate>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGrandParentService" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="150">  
      </asp:DropDownList>  
</FooterTemplate>

Comment: <FooterTemplate>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParentService" runat="server" Width="150">  
      </asp:DropDownList>  
</FooterTemplate>

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NullReferenceException? On the line with "DropDownList ddlParent = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlParentService");" or on the line with "ddlParent.DataSource = GetParentServiceByGrandParent  (Convert.ToInt32((GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlGrandParentService") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value));"?

Comment: I am getting error on the line "ddlParent.DataSource = GetParentServiceByGrandParent (Convert.ToInt32((GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlGrandParentService") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value));"

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the line where you set the `ddlParent.DataSource` to the following:

```
ddlParent.DataSource = GetParentServiceByGrandParent(Convert.ToInt32(ddlGrandParent.SelectedItem.Value));
```

You have to load the parent `DropDownList` from the current `EventArgs` (like you did few lines above) and not from `GridView.FooterRow`. And secondly you have loaded the parent control a few lines above.

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin. But parent dropdownlist does not filtering against the grand parent dropdownlist. How do i get the selected value of the grand parent dropdownlist as i commented out in the above code.

Comment: Sorry I actually don't understand your requirement. Can you please update your code above and add the definition of your <asp:GridView /> control.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference the **GridView1.FooterRow** in the RowCreated event because it is not yet created. You should replace the reference with **e.Row**.

```
ddlParent.DataSource = GetParentServiceByGrandParent  (Convert.ToInt32((GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlGrandParentService") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value));
```

Should be:

```
ddlParent.DataSource = GetParentServiceByGrandParent  (Convert.ToInt32((e.Row.FindControl("ddlGrandParentService") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value));
```

Comment: It's not an answer... You'd better use comments for this.

Comment: @perror - Why is it not an answer? Not arguing, just trying to learn.

Comment: It looks like that you are asking more information about the original question. If you are sure of your answer (and it might be the case), just say that you think this line should be replaced by the second one (and remove the final '?'). It's really a matter of presenting things here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have edited the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, it is much better that way. Good luck for next time ! ;-)